# Помогите с матрицами

Tags: c

В квадратной матрице найти минимальный положительный элемент. Поменять местами строку и столбец, на пересечении которых расположен найденный минимум.
Код работает правильно только если минимум находится внизу справа. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.[image: Вот только так работает правильно]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 500

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n,i,j,p=0,q=0 ;                                
    int mx[N][N];        
    int min,tmp;  

    do
    {
        printf("Введите размерность матрицы:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if ((n < 2) || (n > N))
            {
                printf("Ошибка, n меньше двух или больше 500\n");
            }
    }
   while(((n < 2) || (n > N)));

    printf("Введите элементы матрицы по строкам:\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &mx[i][j]);
            }

    min=mx[0][0]; 
    printf("Исходная матрица:\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(mx[i][j]<min)
                {
                    min=mx[i][j];
                    p=i;
                    q=j;
                }
            printf("%d", mx[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            tmp=mx[i][q];
            mx[i][q]=mx[p][i];
            mx[p][i]=tmp;
        }
    printf("\n\nПолученная матрица:\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) 
            printf("%d", mx[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас задача поиска максимума с ограничениями. Соответственно вы не можете взять за начальное значение произвольный элемент (например первый) ибо вы должны взять за начальное значение первый положительный

```
mmax=-1; 

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(mx[i][j]>0)
                {
                if (mmax=-1){
                    mmax=mx[i][j];
                    p=i;
                    q=j;
                }
                else {
                 if (mmax<mx[i][j]){
                        mmax=mx[i][j];
                        p=i;
                        q=j;
                        }
                }
            printf("%d ", mx[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
```

mmax=-1 кодирует, что мы еще не нашли положительный элемент. После цикла надо проверить, что mmax>0 тогда есть положительный минимум, если mmax=-1 то все элементы в массиве не положительные.